# Customizing The DependencyObject Inheritance Tree

Tags: .net, wpf, dependency-properties, dependencyobject

I'm struggling to find sufficient information about the property Inheritance Tree (or Inheritence Context) used by `DependencyObject` and `DependencyProperty`.

I would like to use the value inheritence capability of `DependencyProperty` outside of a typical WPF page, such that Object A is the logical parent Object B, and thus a value assigned to a property on Object A will automatically propogate to Object B unless it has been locally set (a bit like the `FlowDirection` property works in WPF).

If Object A and Object B are derieved from `DependencyObject`, and *are not* children of a `UIElement`  (in other words, Object A is it's own *root*), then how do you establish the logical tree so that `DependencyProperty` understands that B is a child of A?

The  [Hillberg Freezable Trick](http://www.drwpf.com/blog/Home/tabid/36/EntryID/36/Default.aspx) as well as [Josh Smith's bag of tricks](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ArtificialInheritanceCxt.aspx) aren't quite what I'm looking for. I *don't* want to retrieve properties from an existing element tree... I want to create my own, non-visual element tree... i.e. have control over the inheritence context.

Anyone know where this body of knowledge is hiding?

Comment: I'm curious how you ended up solving your problem.  Did you write your own tree/inheritance/DP mechanism?  Find any libraries to help you on your way?  I'm attempting to do something similar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After much research and muddling through the source code for `DependencyObject`, here's the short answer:

The `InheritenceContext` (the property which reveals the logical parent of an instance) is (like 90% of the useful implementation of `DependencyObject`) marked as internal and thus kept hidden from all code outside of WindowsBase.dll

It is possible to use reflection to set the `_contextParent` field, as well as to call this hidden methods to set the `InheritenceContext`, but at the end of the day its not a clean solution.

After scouring the `DependencyObject` source code, I've gotta say that I'm not impressed. `DependencyObject` could and should have been a very clean, ubiquitous, reusable class.
Instead it is structurally and behaviourly bound to it's inheritors, and even contains specific constants, fields, methods and work-arounds to help Freezable co-exist with the rest of the sub-classes, which not only strays far from good OO design, but also makes an otherwise superb class utterly unusable outside of the WPF framework.

Comment: Cheers for the answer to this interesting question.  It's a shame that these kinds of properties require a specific base class, though I can't think of a better solution shy of language/compiler support (same for Freezable).

Comment: Can you share the solution you went for ? You did your own "DependencyObject" implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're asking about the propagation of values to children that do not override values themselves.

The concept of a WPF element having a child is introduced by `ContentControl` as far as I know.  This comes into play much further down the hierarchy than you want to go.  So, I would assume that if you were to simply derive from `DependencyObject` that this behaviour would not manifest.

Specifically, a child needs to know to ask its parent if it doesn't have a value for a given property.

Interesting question.  I'd like to know the full answer too.